# DropBox integration to MFC application

Tags: mfc, cloud, dropbox

I have an application which will create an encrypted file which i want to upload it to Dropbox  (from no, and later in google Drive also). How can upload this file to dropbox from within the application. I have googled a lot for MFC integration with dropbox but havent come across any useful resource yet. If anyone has implemented it earlier please help..

Comment: Possibly you can make use of CloudBlackbox package of our SecureBlackbox product (C++ edition). It offers a uniform API for major cloud services including Dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

For my own app I initially tried this the hard way, writing wrappers around Google Drive and DropBox to interface directly with their web services.

After a while I gave up on that (because the APIs were difficult to work with and there was almost no sample code of any kind) and instructed users to install the respective Windows clients for these services so that uploading was as simple as copying the file to their local Google Drive or DropBox folders.

It may not be the solution you want but it has worked well for me.